# Why is my `debian-slim` container image much larger than when using `alpine`?

Tags: debian, containers, alpine

I'd like to use `debian:bookworm` as my base container image. But I find that the container image grows (according to `dive`) very quickly as I install applications using `apt-get`.

Disclaimer: These "benchmark" results are averaged from a few repeated runs on my machine, but I think broadly representative of the problem.

**Comparing for a single app**

```
FROM debian:bookworm-slim
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends nginx
```

```
FROM alpine:3.18.2
RUN apk add --no-cache nginx
```

which results in:

| base | build time | size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| alpine | 2.3s | 9.2 MB |
| debian-slim | 5.1s | 132 MB |

`debian-slim` takes longer because `apt-get update` is slower, but the base image difference is significant for a single application.

**Comparing with multiple apps**

```
FROM debian:bookworm-slim
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends nginx curl wget git iputils-ping rsync unzip && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archives /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

```
FROM alpine:3.18.2
RUN apk add --no-cache nginx curl wget git iputils-ping rsync unzip
```

| base | build time | size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| alpine | 3.2s | 23 MB |
| debian-slim | 9.0s | 201 MB |

Alpine increased by 0.9s and 13.8 MB.
Debian increased by 3.9s and 69 MB.

**File list**

Using `docker run --rm -it <tag> du -h > debian.txt`

alpine: https://pastebin.com/mHTHDFwW
debian-slim: https://pastebin.com/wTpuYGDD

About 50 MB seems to be related to `perl`?

**Example of extreme case**

I have an image that includes a number of build tools (Java, Go, NodeJS, ...), which will obviously be heavy, but I'm still surprised that it amounts to 7.1 GB.
But it may not be the fault of debian/apt.
Just running `pip3 install ansible` adds 565 MB, of which 222 MB is for `fortinet` (which I imagine few people use), so I guess the lesson is it be vigilant when using package managers, and not use the broad `nginx` or `ansible`, but more specific/explicit packages.

**Question**

Why does Debian grow so much more, and install applications much slower?
This is especially relevant for heavy container images, where the difference can be 100 MB vs 1 GB.

From what I read online, Alpine is more bleeding-edge, comparable to Arch, with community-grade packages, while Debian packages are more trustworthy. For enterprise use, in a security-critical environment, it seems necessary to use Debian packages, but it's also hard to justify such large images. Is Alpine trustworthy for enterprise use? (Ideally all binaries would be reproducible, and signed by the developers, so independent builds would be trustworthy, but I understand that we're far from that?).

Can anything be done to reduce the Debian size/time to build? One option is to install binaries manually. `apt-get update` could be made faster by using an apt-proxy on the build server?

One explanation could be that the alpine image has many built-in dependencies (busybox?), while `debian`/`debian-slim` needs to add them?

Comment: Your not filtering best practice and cleaning up all the Debian apt metadata

Comment: My understanding was that this was automatically executed by Docker on each RUN. But to verify, I added it, and the image size is now 201 MB.

Comment: This question was downvoted. Why? I think it's a fair question what causes the container image to be almost 10x larger than alpine.

Comment: The down vote is mainly for the opinion based "is it worth it", which is "best" is unanswerable without criteria to measure against, size is one measure, but for example developer familiarity with Debian based systems may speed up devely or availability of applications packaged for Debian may tilt things in it's favour. But there are also 2 other independent questions, 1) why is alpine smaller (search musl Vs glibc) 2) how do I make Debian smaller

Comment: Have you compared the list of binaries installed on both images? What about the size of the shared libraries? The primary difference between Alpine and everything else is that Alpine uses MUSL-libc, while Debian/Ubuntu/RedHat/Fedora/Arch/etc all use glibc, which by itself is substantially larger.

Comment: @hardillb I've modified the text to more carefully express the dilemma I'm in.

Comment: @larsks I've added a file list to the question text. It seems that the debian package defaults to include supporting packages, like perl, which I imagine can be used as modules, for example in nginx.